telnet Connection to SMTP Server Immediately Closed, but nc Connection Succeeds
I am experiencing an issue where telnet immediately closes the connection to my SMTP server, while nc successfully connects to the same port. Here's what I've observed:

When using telnet to connect to the SMTP server on port 25 and 587, the connection is established but immediately closed with the message "Connection closed by foreign host."

# telnet <ip> 25
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.


However, using nc (Netcat) to check the connectivity on the same port succeeds without any issues.

# nc -vz <ip> 25
Connection to <ip> 25 port [tcp/smtp] succeeded!


The same result applies when testing port 587 with nc:

nc -vz <ip> 587
Connection to <ip> 587 port [tcp/submission] succeeded!

Despite the successful nc connections, telnet behaves differently and immediately closes the connection. Could anyone provide insights into why telnet might be closing the connection while nc succeeds? Are there any specific issues or configurations I should check for this discrepancy?
I expected telnet to establish a connection and allow me to interact with the SMTP server, similar to how nc was able to establish a successful connection.

The -z option prevents nc from noticing when the remote server disconnects.
